# Nodejs Sequelize transaction using async/await not rolling back

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

```
    let transaction;
      try {
        transaction = await connection.sequelize.transaction();
        const employee = await Employee.findOne({
          where: {
            uuid: req.params.uuid
          }
        });
        if (employee) {
          await Account.destroy( {
            where: {
              uuid: employee.accountUuid
            }
          }, {transaction});
          await Employee.destroy({
            where: {
              uuid: req.params.uuid
            }
          }, {transaction});  
          await transaction.commit();

          return res.status(200).json({
            messages: messages.MSG_SUCCESS
          });
        } else {
          return res.status(404).json({
            message: constants.EMPLOYEE + messages.MSG_NOT_FOUND
          });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (transaction) await transaction.rollback();
        return res.status(500).json({
          message: messages.MSG_CANNOT_DELETE + constants.EMPLOYEE
        });

  }
```

I use this piece of code to create transaction. It works fine until the employee deletion failed. It does call rollback in the console.log but the account is still deleted in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction should be passed in same object as `where` object.

```
await Account.destroy({
   where: {
      uuid: employee.accountUuid
   },
   transaction
});
```

Reference: [Sequelize destroy](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-destroy)

Comment: Tks bro. I was mistaken it with create.